# How to parse JSON response in a built step in jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, httprequest, jenkins-plugins

In order to industrialize the deployments of an IBM product, I'm going to use its REST API interfaces.
I plan to use jenkins in order to orchestrate the calls to the REST APIs.
I'm still wondering if it's a good idea...?
If so, is there any way to simply parse the JSON responses in order to be able to make some conditions in the steps?
Thanks.

Comment: Could it be written as a python script or a shell script? Then, let `Jenkins` execute the script.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't say what you're using the API for, but if you have the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin), you could use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)

Something like

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
URL apiUrl = "https://some.website/api/someFunction".toURL()
List json = new JsonSlurper().parse(apiUrl.newReader())

// do stuff with the json object
```

I'm not quite sure how you would take this and use it directly for conditional build steps *during the execution of the job*, though.

An alternative approach is to generate a set of jobs with the appropriate steps based on the API response, using the [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin). This sort of thing can be used for stuff like reading a list of SCM branches and generating jobs for each of them. That may or may not be what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. I will test the plugin.I need to orchestrate API calls in order to deploy some artifacts. Each API call contributes to the delivery and I need to parse the JSON answer of each one before going to the next build step.

Answer (score 1):

JQ https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ is a JSON parser for bash. I have used it in the past and its beautiful.

You can download JQ to your Jenkins server, and then call JQ in your build step bash scripts

Comment: Ok I will test it and give a feedback.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Pipeline Job, you will be happy with [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin)

Comment: Kindly elobrate

Comment: Probably referring to the readJSON step: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md

Comment: See this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174084/parsing-json-on-jenkins-pipeline-groovy