# JSON on the command line with jq in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, json, shell, jenkins, npm

I used `jq -r '.version' package.json` command to filter the version from package.json file using the terminal.

Can we use `jq` command in Jenkins shell without locally installing it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using "jq", use the `groovy.json.JsonSlurper` class to parse the same output that "jq" can parse.

If "jsonStr" is a string variable with legal json content, here's an example using this:

```
def stuff = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr).stuff
```

This will get the "stuff" property in the json string and assign it to the "stuff" variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, in the `shell` build step, you can only execute commands which are available to the shell therefor you have to install `jq` on your system and it must be accessible by jenkins.

Comment: Can't we use a plugin for that? Then I need to install `jq` in the local server for executing Jenkins Shell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062872/how-to-parse-json-response-in-a-built-step-in-jenkins